# sort dictionary with float values in python

Tags: python

I'm sorting dictionary with float values to ascending order. Here's my code

```
dicdata = {'mike': 15.12, 'jenny': 2.53, 'glenn' : 5.16, 'Meo': 1.01}

sorted_dicdata = sorted(dicdata.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

The output is not accurate. it gives me
glenn:5.16
mike:15.12
jenny:2.53
meo:1.01
How can i fix this?

Comment: Just to note: they're `float` values - not to be confused with `decimal.Decimal` values

Comment: Why do you think it isn't accurate?

Comment: Also - from your stated output `glenn:5.16 mike:15.12 jenny:2.53 meo:1.01` - that looks very much like you've copy and pasted an attempt at converting it back to a `dict` - rather than a list of 2-tuples which `sorted` which return in this case. Can't help but feel you haven't posted your full code here...

Comment: Does sorting dictionary with float values are unreliable?

Comment: @Newboy11 dictionaries, by default, are unsorted. It has nothing to do with the float values

Comment: I solved my inaccuracy problem using:
dicdata[Key] = float(values)

Answer (score 3):

The following code works if you want from decimal to the ascending order

```
    >>> import operator
    >>> print sorted(dicdata.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    [('Meo', 1.01), ('jenny', 2.53), ('glenn', 5.16), ('mike', 15.12)]
```

Comment: Works pretty well and fast in __python3__ - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following correctly sorts the dictionary (Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4.2)

```
>>> import operator
>>> dicdata={'mike':15.12, 'jenny':2.53, 'glenn': 5.16, 'Meo': 1.01}
>>> sorted_dicdata = sorted(dicdata.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),        reverse=True)
>>> sorted_dicdata
[('mike', 15.12), ('glenn', 5.16), ('jenny', 2.53), ('Meo', 1.01)]
```

I put quotes around the dictionary keys since I assume they are meant to be strings.

Answer (score 0):

Way I found - convert dict to pandas series, sort, and convert back.

```py
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(dictionary)
series.sort_values(axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', ignore_index=False, key=None)
series.to_dict()
```